# Is placing a backorder with GoDaddy and DomainMonster enough to avoid a public domain auction?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-backorder

A domain name I want to buy currently has a status of `pending delete` with GoDaddy.  I've placed backorders with *GoDaddy* and *DomainMonster*, but is this enough?

I have googled and read a lot, but am struggling with conflicting advice that seems to go out of date quickly.  *DropCatch*, *NameJet* and *SnapNames* are all frequently recommended, but other people say that *GoDaddy* has a monopoly on dropping names originally hosted by them.

I also want to avoid a situation where I cause a public auction and end up paying more than needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, no, placing a backorder with GoDaddy for a domain that they currently hold does not guarantee they will catch the name.

The domain I wanted to buy dropped yesterday, and was picked up by DropCatch.  Based on this experience, next time I would place orders with multiple backorder services to increase the chance of winning the domain.